# What ID does a ComboBox reference?

Tags: ms-access

I am *attempting* to maintain and fix a horribly out-of-date CRM designed by an ex-employee ~4-5 years ago in Access 2007. I have brought it into Access 2013 and fixed a ton of stuff up, but I am still running into many problems.

I spent a good 4 hours today attempting to figure out why certain values didn't line up. These values were being pulled from a SELECT statement on a Combo Box over a stored Query which simply returns a table with a few extra rows. Great.

However this value (a number) doesn't appear to correlate with what we expect. I enter in one value, save the ticket, and a completely different value gets stored into the table. Opening up the ticket, I see the value that I expect. Digging deeper, I found the following difference:

```
Set value_1 = Me.RegistrationID // What's being stored in the table
Set value_2 = Me.RegistrationID.Column(0) // What we expect
```

Surprise surprise! This is a **Combo Box** and *some value* is being stored in the table. The Control Source is "RegistrationID" and the Row Source is the query in question.

However I do not know what it is! This specific value correlating to the Combo Box *appears* to pull the correct data when we later open the tickets. However I have a strong feeling that this could be why many tickets from before one of the rows was deleted all appear to have invalid RegistrationID's.

- How badly can this break?
- How easily can we correct tens of thousands of tickets?
- How can I fix this to store the correct value?

Comment: You need to look at the Bound Column and compare it to the order of the fields in the rowsource query. As long as the first column doesn't change in the query there shouldn't be any issue with saving to the database

Comment: @dbmitch, that's my problem: we need to get the Registration ID directly from the case. It is pulling some other number that I cannot easily correlate, and it therefore breaks other forms in the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I expect is happening.

Your combo box row source is based on a Select query which returns and displays multiple rows. For example:

```
Select RegistrationID, CustomerID, CustomerName From MyTable;
```

The Control Source for the combo box is bound to RegistrationID which is part of the Forms Record Source.

The issue is the bound column. If we set the bound column in our example to 1, then we get the behavior your are describing with:

```
Set value_1 = Me.RegistrationID - Set's value to CustomerID (may appear correct)
Set value_2 = Me.RegistrationID.Column(0) - position 0 from our query (RegistrationID)
```

Further building on our query example, you can say:

```
Me.TextBox1 = Me.RegistrationID.Column(0) - RegistrationID
Me.TextBox2 = Me.RegistrationID.Column(1) - CustomerID
Me.TextBox3 = Me.RegistrationID.Column(2) - CustomerName
```

Comment: Aha! Bound column was set to 0, which (for whatever reason) is the index of the query (ie, 3 entries down was returning 2). It looks like what was happening is that the query is sorted by another value that gets changed occasionally, so the index would also have been moved. I set the bound column to 1, which returned what I *expected* to be at column 0, aka the Registration ID. Now all is good. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0):

The RegistrationID is what normally **should** be stored in the table.
As long as your form shows any values that directly relate to this RegistrationID you're fine.

Answer (score 0):

I would start by checking to see under the format setting to see if column widths are set properly and I would also check under the data section to see if the bound column is correct. I might also throw in an after update macro/vba sub routine that saves the record. Hope this helps.